# MySQL managers. What are advantages and shortcomings of the SQLyog and EMS SQl Manager

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

I need to find most useful MySQL manager. And I found SQLyog and EMS SQL like most popular. Maybe I'm not right. So, please, advise me something.

Comment: I think that the choice is subjective. I like sqlyog but a lot o people I know prefer for example heidisql. So try different gui until you find the one most suitable for your goals.

Comment: I can advice you to try [dbForge Studio for MySQL](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely a subjective issue. From my experience:

### SQL YOG

- More comfortable work with many open queries.
- Better export options.
- Better at auto formatting queries.

### EMS

- Faster!
- On connecting, reopens all queries you had open the last time you were connected to each DB. Very helpful.
- DB connections tree easier to use when working with many DBs.

Bottom line: I prefer EMS, but when I have to export large amounts of data I use YOG.

Hope this will help you choose. They're both good.

Comment: Thanx a lot. There are just many solutions, also heidisql is popular thing. So I think I'll make my choise with my experiense. Now I try heidisql.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this question has a negative vote. Seems like a legitimate question to me.

From my experience HeldiSQL (as a base since it's free), however, if you can afford both EMS and SQL Yog, having both is the ultimate toolset. Price wise, both are equally the same; so I would use each and see which one you like the best.

Functionality wise, they also are equally the same. Different UI/UX so this is why you must use both to find the one that fits your preference. **Huge note:** Searching in SQL Yog and HeldiSQL is better than EMS.